# Ubuntu Linux Gnome Desktop Launcher Icon formats?

Tags: linux, gnome, desktop, ubuntu-10.10, launcher

A few years back PNG graphics could be used as launcher icons.
This does not work on Ubuntu 10.10, while SVG works.
Is there any reliable documentation?

Comment: Documentation on what? The "migration" itself? Software to convert between the two? Clarification is required, here.

Answer (score 0):

PNG works fine as a launcher icon. Is there a specific icon that's your problem?